# Django3.0: Images from database not showing-up after debug=False

Tags: django, django-templates, django-settings, django-media

After `debug=False` in my settings. Images from database not showing up otherwise they were. Static files are showing up real good. Even my media files were showing up before `debug=False`. Database has correct addresses of files but covers not showing up.

Following is the code, how I am accessing cover images.

```
<div class="product-top">
     <img src="{{ product.cover.url }}" alt="book-image">
     <h5>{{ product.title }}</h5>
</div>
```

my settings.py related code:

```
import os
import django_heroku

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
TEMP_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')


# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'abc'


# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'abc@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'xyz'
EMAIL_PORT = 25
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'abc@gmail.com'
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
BASE_URL = '127.0.0.1:8000'

MANAGERS = (
    ('abc', "abc@gmail.com"),
)

ADMINS = MANAGERS


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'debug_toolbar',
    'crispy_forms',
    # myapps

    'myapp',

]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.User'

STRIPE_SECRET_KEY = 'abc'
STRIPE_PUB_KEY = 'abc'

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    # Simplified static file serving.
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMP_DIR]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'project.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
## Password hashing (included)

    PASSWORD_HASHERS = [
    
        'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2PasswordHasher',
        'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2SHA1PasswordHasher',
        'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptSHA256PasswordHasher',
    ]

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_br = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,
                         'bookrepo/static')


STATIC_seller = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'seller/static')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    STATIC_br, STATIC_seller
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles/')

# MEDIA INFORMATION:

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

as my `terminal` says after `debug=false`:

```
[23/Aug/2020 23:07:00] "GET /media/covers/product1.PNG HTTP/1.1" 404 11974
```

as my `terminal` says after `debug=true`:

```
[23/Aug/2020 23:25:15] "GET /media/covers/product1.PNG HTTP/1.1" 200 103898
```

Comment: When using runserver with `DEBUG=True` url patterns to serve your static and media files are added. To serve your files in production you need to configure your webserver to serve those directories

Comment: @lain kindly if you can show me way out with some relevant code. I even deployed to heroku, static files are showing up there too but not media files.

Comment: This is less to do with code and more to do with configuring your deployment, see the Django docs for staticfiles (this also applies to media files when using file based backend) https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/deployment/

Answer (score 1):

It is worth noting that django itself does not serve static and media files when debug is false.You should use a reverse proxy like ha proxy or nginx if you are in production otherwise set debug to true for local development
Below is an example for nginx server block that serves your application, static and media files.

```
server {
    server_name your_server_ip;
    proxy_read_timeout 600s;
    client_max_body_size 25M;

    location /static {
            alias /home/trello/static/;
    }


    location /media {
            alias /home/trello/media/;
    }


    location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_redirect off;
    }
```

}

Comment: sorry I am at beginner level. So can you please spoon feed me that **where and how** to put this block for local server `http://127.0.0.1:8000`. Thanks

Comment: If you are on Linux, you  should install nginx then create the configuration script 'your_configuration.conf' at 'etc/nginx/sites-available/' then add your block and run the command: 'ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/reverse-proxy.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/your_configuration.conf' to symlink then finally 'nginx -t' to test the configuration